# How to save a page as HTML in CorelDraw 2019?

Tags: coreldraw

There was a menu item File->Export HTML in earlier CorelDraw versions. But I do not see this or similar menu item in CorelDraw 2019. So how to export/save page to HTML in CorelDraw 2019?